# Power Automate delete trigger does not bring custom columns

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

I have a **CustomID** single line of text type column in my list. I have added a delete trigger action in my Power Automate but in the subsequent actions I don't see the "CustomID" column, only I could see the out-of-the-box columns like ID, Name, etc, but we don't see the **custom columns**.

[image: Power Automate Delete Trigger]

Does anyone know the reason for this? I know that we can not access all columns while deleting an item, this limitation was there earlier, wanted to check whether still, this limitation is there or if is there any other way to get all columns access while deleting an item in Power Automate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flow triggers after the item is deleted. It only give the below information.

```
{
"ID": 2,
"Name": "Title2",
"FileNameWithExtension": "Title2",
"DeletedByUserName": "Mark",
"TimeDeleted": "2019-12-12T23:04:15Z",
"IsFolder": false
}
```

So in your case you cannot find the dynamic content because the item is already deleted hence you will get 404 item not found. → So OOTB it is not possible,

What I can suggest to you, to apply a work around I can think that you add a flag (custom column) called Delete Y/N. Trigger against this field update and apply the rest of your business logic.

I believe this answer to your question definitely.